# upgrade angularjs code from 1.0.3 to 1.4.9

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angularJS and trying to get the code given in  fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atXAC/11/ upgraded to 1.4.9.

```
myApp.directive('ngCustomblur', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr['ngCustomblur']);      
        element.bind('blur', function(event) {        
        scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(scope, {$event:event});
        });
    });
}
}]);
```

Please let me know what changes need to be done.
currently the code is in 1.0.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is the issue here  ?

Comment: I am using angular 1.4.9 and unable to get the code working. The code in the fiddle is written in 1.0.3

Comment: What errors are you getting in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue is that the later versions of `angularjs` library made it a standard to create a controller, which is a little different from the current syntax which you are using in jsfiddle.

**JS CODE:**

```
//defining a controller
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.onBlur = function(){        
      $scope.hasFocus = false;
   }
}
```

[Working demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atXAC/14/)